# Encrypt HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developping an asp mvc # application. I want to encrypt an `HttpPostedFileBase` (`file` in the code below is the `HttpPostedFileBase` that I want to encrypt):

```
void Upload(string target, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
FullPath dest = ParsePath(target);
FileInfo path = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dest.Directory.FullName, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)));

//file.SaveAs(path.FullName);

MemoryStream _MemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
file.InputStream.CopyTo(_MemoryStream);

DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(_MemoryStream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
//Here I want to save my crypted stream to the path
//....
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The HttpPostedFileBase is a completed transfer from the client browser. It's already been transmitted over the wire and the data is on your server by the time you get hold of it here. Are you trying to encrypt before saving to disk? If so, you shouldn't try using the InputStream to do any writing.

Comment: I want to encrypt it just before saving in my server

Comment: Well, copy the `file.InputStream` into a `Stream` object, and then encrypt that object. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: before saving the file, i must encrypt it. So I don't know how to write the encrypted stream into a file or a fileInfo,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(_MemoryStream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    using (var output = new FileStream(path.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        crStream.CopyTo(output);
    }
```

Comment: I believe the CryptoSteam should be wrapped around the FileStream and copy to the CryptoSteam, as in:

    using (var output = new FileStream(path.FullName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(output, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        file.InputStream.CopyTo(crStream);
    }

That way, it's more like: inputStream->crypto->file